# Splitting list elements based on substring

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, data-manipulation

How do I split the elements in this element based on the string before the dot without explicitly writing it in code?

```
lst = ['ds_a.cola','ds_a.colb','ds_b.cola','ds_b.colb']
```

Since there are two variants of 'ds'. I want two lists.

```
lst_dsa = ['ds_a.cola','ds_a.colb']
lst_dsb = ['ds_b.cola','ds_b.colb']
```

My old code was:

```
lst_dsa = []
lst_dsb = []
for item in lst :
    if "ds_a" in item:
        lst_dsa.append(item)
    else:
        lst_dsb.append(item)
```

But I can't use this since there might be more than 2, like, ds_c,ds_d....
How do I achieve this in python?

Comment: Are the groups always contiguous?

Comment: What do you mean be contiguous? The groups seperating the columns are always mentioned before the dot and they may or may not contain underscore. Ex: dataset1.colA, dataset_09.colA

Answer (score 3):

Use a dict and hold the data

```
from collections import defaultdict
lst = ['ds_a.cola','ds_a.colb','ds_b.cola','ds_b.colb','ds_x.cola','ds_x.colb']
data = defaultdict(list)
for entry in lst:
  a,_ = entry.split('.')
  data[a].append(entry)
print(data)
```

output

```
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'ds_a': ['ds_a.cola', 'ds_a.colb'], 'ds_b': ['ds_b.cola', 'ds_b.colb'], 'ds_x': ['ds_x.cola', 'ds_x.colb']})
```

Comment: @DaniMesejo You are absolutely right.. The funny thing is there is another answer that looks the same :-)

Comment: @DaniMesejo What do you try to claim ? Please share it.

Comment: You can add `maxsplit` to avoid possible `ValueError`. `entry.split('.', 1)` Or/And you can use `a, *_ = entry.split('.', 1)` To not get error if there's no `"."` in string.

Answer (score 2):

Try `itertools.groupby`:

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> [list(v) for _, v in groupby(lst, key=lambda x: x[x.find('_') + 1])]
[['ds_a.cola', 'ds_a.colb'], ['ds_b.cola', 'ds_b.colb']]
>>>
```

Comment: The groups separating the columns are always mentioned before the dot and they may or may not contain underscore. So will this break there's no underscore?

Comment: @Fazli It depends, you should first try it then.

Answer (score 0):

You can map them:

```
from collections import defaultdict

lst = ['ds_a.cola','ds_a.colb','ds_b.cola','ds_b.colb']
ds_dict = defaultdict(list)

for item in lst:
    key, value = item.split(".")
    ds_dict[key].append(value)

print(dict(ds_dict))
```

Output:

```
{'ds_a': ['cola', 'colb'], 'ds_b': ['cola', 'colb']}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
 d = dict()
 for item in lst:
     key = item.split(".")[0]
     if key not in d.keys():
         d[key] = list()
     d[key].append(item)
```

Answer (score 0):

use two repeating regular expressions: one for ds_a period and one or more words and ds period and one or more words.  Ignore the empty group and use a defaultdict to add values to the set.

```
 lst = ['ds_a.cola','ds_a.colb','ds_b.cola','ds_b.colb']
 pattern=r"(?:\bds_a\.\w+\b\s*)*(?:\bds_b\.\w+\b\s*)*"
```

string=" ".join(lst)

```
 groups=re.findall(pattern,string)
 dict=defaultdict(set)
 for group in groups:
     for item in group.split():
         if item !="":
             print(item)
             key,*value=item.split('.')
             dict[key].add(value[0])
```

print(dict)

output:

```
 defaultdict(<class 'set'>, {'ds_a': {'cola', 'colb'}, 'ds_b': {'cola', 'colb'}})
```